# Jest Enzyme Test Case mock API with Moxios not working

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, enzyme, moxios

Here is the Component Code where i call API with getAllData method and set data to the state:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
 state = {
   allStatus: []
 }
 componentDidMount() {
  this.getAllData();
 }
 getAllData = async() => {
   let res = await apiCalls(`${Config.masterUrl}/ContentState`, 'GET', {}, `/user-data`, false);
   if (res) {
     this.setState({allStatus: res});
   }
  }
}
```

Here are the Test cases first I call componentDidMount and call method getAllData then mock API with moxios but it doesn't mock the request.

```
describe('Render MyComponent Component', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = setup(initialState);
    moxios.install();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
  })
  
  it("should call getAllData API Success",  async(done) => {
    const responseData = {
      status: 200,
      error: null,
      data: [Array] // for example
    }
    await wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
    await wrapper.instance().getAllData()
    moxios.wait(function() {
      const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
      request.respondWith(responseData)
      expect(wrapper.instance().state.allStatus.length).not.toBe(0)
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: How can the call to `getAllData` ever complete, if you haven't yet configured moxios to respond to the request it's making? Also you shouldn't be calling component methods directly, the call to `componentDidMount` already calls `getAllData`, and `componentDidMount` gets called by React once the component is mounted.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please add a test?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to call `componentDidMount()` and `getAllData()` methods manually.

> As of Enzyme v3, the `shallow` API does call React lifecycle methods such as `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`

2. You should install `moxios` firstly, then shallow render the component. Because the mocks should be ready when we shallow render(call `componentDidMount` and `getAllData`) the component.
3. The return value of [respondWith](https://github.com/axios/moxios/blob/master/index.js#L262) method is a promise, you should make sure it's resolved/rejected. So you need to make assertions after the promise is resolved or rejected.

E.g.

`MyComponent.tsx`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

async function apiCalls(url, method) {
  return axios({ url, method }).then((res) => res.data);
}

export class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    allStatus: [],
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllData();
  }
  getAllData = async () => {
    let res = await apiCalls(`http://localhost:3000/api/ContentState`, 'GET');
    if (res) {
      this.setState({ allStatus: res });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return <div>MyComponent</div>;
  }
}
```

`MyComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import moxios from 'moxios';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';

describe('Render MyComponent Component', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install();
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent></MyComponent>);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
  });

  it('should call getAllData API Success', (done) => {
    const responseData = {
      status: 200,
      response: [1, 2, 3],
    };
    moxios.wait(function () {
      const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
      request.respondWith(responseData).then(() => {
        expect(wrapper.state('allStatus')).toHaveLength(3);
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65702308/MyComponent.test.tsx (5.34 s)
  Render MyComponent Component
    ✓ should call getAllData API Success (246 ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 MyComponent.tsx |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 17                
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.505 s
```

Comment: What if in the componentDidMount call multiple API then how do i know which API is testing with your test case. Example my component have 2 API call now:  componentDidMount() { this.getAllData(); this.getUserList()}